# How do I find the median in O(h) time?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

This is for a homework problem -

I need to find the median of a Binary Search Tree in O(h) time - meaning, I cant go through the whole tree to find it. I need to find the median by going through the left or right side of the tree, in a recursion solution.

I've placed an index into each node of the BST, using inorder traversal.
So if a BST has 99 nodes, the smallest node has an index of 1, the next smallest has index of 2 etc etc...while the largest node has index of 99. THis indexing is also required of the assignment.

So whichever side is heavier, has the median.

So here's what I was thinking:

if the left side has more nodes median is on the left. if right side has more nodes, median is on the right. if the left and right sides have equal num of nodes, median is the main root of the whole tree.

But I can't think of how the nodes' indexes would play a role in any of this. I was thinking of using the difference of 2 nodes' indexes to see if 1 side is heavier, but this would require me to go through the whole tree I think, so this would be O(n).

Please set me on a clearer path or a hint or 2.

Comment: Is there a misprint in O(h) here: "I need to find the median of a Binary Search Tree in O(h) time"? Or how "h" and "n" are related?

Comment: The tree knows it's own size, right? So if tree has 99 nodes, then the *median* is the node with index 50. Locating node with index 50 in a Binary Search Tree is a simple Binary Search.

Comment: @Renat  h is the height of the BST.

Comment: If you show us the code that holds the binary tree (including the indexes) it is probably easy to write the recursive method. @Andreas solution, to find index=50, seems to be the way to solve this.